# Does something like Python generator exist in objective-c?

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, cocoa

Does something like [Python generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) exist in objective-c ?

I have following code on few places, so is there some way to simplify it ?

```
int maxWinInRow = [self maxWinInRow];

// how many wins in row
for (int i=1; i <= maxWinInRow; i++) {

    NSString * key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
    NSNumber * value = [_winsInRow valueForKey:key ];
    int numbeOfWinInRow = value.intValue;


    // only this line is specific
    gameScore = gameScore + ( pow(6,i) * numbeOfWinInRow);
}
```

Comment: Refactor it into a method you can call...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be specific, there is no such generator pattern built inside Objective C programming language. However with the introduction of "blocks" in Objective C (and C with LLVM) it has become somewhat possible to build your own generator pattern in Objective C.

If you are serious to learn this, you can go through [this article](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-10-30-generators-in-objective-c.html) by Mike Ash.

However, please be cautious when working with blocks, as it occasionally incurs extra overhead of memory management or else it might result a potential memory leak in your app. So if you want to use the described pattern, please make sure you have the proper understanding of "blocks". Otherwise, I would always advise you to refactor your code to build a basic method that would work as your stub as described by Wain. Certainly that wont allow the lazy initialization that the pattern implies. However, it's a better than nothing solution in Objective C.